# Why is the tangent bundle the disjoint union of tangent spaces?

Tags: differential-geometry, set-theory, manifolds, tangent-spaces, tangent-bundle

Some books (and actually wikipedia too) define tangent bundle $TM$ of a manifold $M$ as the disjoint union of tangent spaces. Then, they write:

\begin{equation}
TM=\bigsqcup_{x\in M} T_xM=\bigcup_{x\in M} \{x\}\times T_xM \tag{1}
\end{equation}
Where $TM_x$ is the tangent space in the point $x$. So the elements of $TM$ are the couples

\begin{equation}
(x,v)\quad x\in M, v\in T_xM
\end{equation}

But when I look up the definition of disjoint union, I find something (apparently) different. For example, on wikipedia, the disjoint union of a family of sets $\{A_i, i\in I\}$
(where, as far as understand $I$ index set) is defined as:

\begin{equation}
\bigsqcup_{i\in I}A_i=\bigcup_{i\in I}\{(x,i): x\in A_i\}
\tag{2}
\end{equation}

I can't really find the similarity between $(1)$ and $(2)$. Is the index set replaced by the set of tangent spaces? Also, the subscript of $\bigcup$ is quite different. In $(1)$ we have the points of the manifold while in $(2)$ we have the indexes. Can someone explain to me the relation between these?

Comment: That is just relabeling and swapping the order of the pair.  You are indexing the tangent spaces $T_xM$ by the point in $x\in M$ (and I'd personally use $(i,x)$ instead of $(x,i)$, so it agrees with lexicographic ordering when we define ordinal arithmetics, for example).

Comment: So the manifold $M$ is the index set and we are just swapping the couple. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, in the case of the tangent bundle, the index set is $M$ and the definition writes the pair with index (that is, the element from $M$) first. In the second the index set is $I$ and the definitions writes the pair with the index second. It's the same thing, just a matter of notation.

Comment: Ok, well, this clears my doubt.